# How to add a camera to each player for multiplayer in LLAPI UNET unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried to make multiplayer online game in Unity using LLAPI from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGkkaNkq8co. Everything is working well and I am also able to add Z-Axis movement for player and build Client in WebGL. However, I tried to add camera to each player by adding camera as a child of Player Prefeb, and write some codes to disenble camera in SpawnPlayer function in Client Script when Player is not local player, but it did not work. Players still used the same camera.

I want each player to have their own view. Is there any solution to this ? Thank in advance.

**Client Script**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Text;

public class Player {
    public string playerName;
    public GameObject avatar;
    public int connectionId;
}

public class Client : MonoBehaviour {

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 10;
    private int port = 5701;

    private int hostId;
    private int webHostId;

    private int reliableChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;

    private int ourClientId;
    private int connectionId;

    private float connectionTime;
    private bool isConnected = false;
    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private string playerName;

    public GameObject playerPrefab; // to Add player to the client
    public Dictionary<int,Player> players = new Dictionary<int, Player>();

    public void Connect() {
        // Does the player have a name ?
        string pName = GameObject.Find("NameInput").GetComponent<InputField>().text; // get Text from InputField
        if (pName == "") 
        {
            Debug.Log("You must enter a name");
            return;

        }
        playerName = pName;

        NetworkTransport.Init();
        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);
        //hostId = NetworkTransport.AddWebsocketHost(topo, 0);
        connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, "127.0.0.1", port, 0, out error);//"127.0.0.1 is local host IP"

        connectionTime = Time.time;
        isConnected = true;

    }


    private void Update() {
        if (!isConnected)
            return;


        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;
        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
        switch (recData) {

            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                Debug.Log("Receiving: " + msg);
                string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');

                switch (splitData[0]) {
                    case "ASKNAME":
                        OnAskName(splitData);
                        break;
                    case "CNN":
                        SpawnPlayer(splitData[1], int.Parse(splitData[2]));
                        break;
                    case "DC":
                        PlayerDisconnected(int.Parse(splitData[1]));
                        break;
                    case "ASKPOSITION":
                        OnAskPosition(splitData);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Debug.Log("Invalid message: " + msg);
                        break;                  
                }

                break;           
        }

    }

        private void OnAskName(string[] data) 
        {
            // Set this client's ID
               ourClientId = int.Parse(data[1]);

        // Send our name to the server
            Send("NAMEIS|" + playerName, reliableChannel);

            // Create all the other players
            for(int i = 2; i < data.Length - 1; i++) {
                string[] d = data[i].Split('%');
                SpawnPlayer(d[0], int.Parse(d[1]));

             }
        }

        private void SpawnPlayer(string playerName, int cnnId) {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(playerPrefab) as GameObject;
        // Is this ours?
        if (cnnId == ourClientId) {
            // Add mobility
            go.AddComponent<PlayerMotor>(); // Add script Motor
            GameObject.Find("Canvas").SetActive(false);
            GameObject.Find("Main Camera").SetActive(false);
            isStarted = true;
        } 

            Player p = new Player();
               p.avatar = go;
               p.playerName = playerName;
               p.connectionId = cnnId;
               p.avatar.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = playerName;
               players.Add(cnnId, p);

              **if (cnnId == ourClientId) {
               p.avatar.GetComponentInChildren<Cemara>().enabled = true;

              }else {
               p.avatar.GetComponentInChildren<Cemara>().enabled = false;
              }**

        }

        private void Send(string message, int channelId) {
               Debug.Log("Sending : " + message);
               byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
               NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, connectionId, channelId, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
        }

        private void PlayerDisconnected(int cnnId) {
            Destroy(players[cnnId].avatar);
            players.Remove(cnnId);         
        }

    private void OnAskPosition(string[] data) {
                if (!isStarted)
                    return;


               for (int i = 1; i <= data.Length-1;i++) // update positions of all players
               {
                   string[] d = data[i].Split('%');

                   // Prevent the server from updating us
                   if(ourClientId != int.Parse(d[0])) {
                       Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;
                       position.x = float.Parse(d[1]);
                       position.y = float.Parse(d[2]);
                       position.z = float.Parse(d[3]);
                       Debug.Log(position.z);
                       players[int.Parse(d[0])].avatar.transform.position = position;
                   }                   
               }
        // Send our own position
                Vector3 myPosition = players[ourClientId].avatar.transform.position;
                string m = "MYPOSITION|" + myPosition.x.ToString() + '|' + myPosition.y.ToString()  + '|' + myPosition.z.ToString();
                Send(m, unreliableChannel);
         }
}
```

**Server Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ServerClient {
    public int connectionId;
    public string playerName;
    public Vector3 position;
}

public class Server : MonoBehaviour {

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 10;
    private int port = 5701;

    private int hostId;
    private int webHostId;

    private int reliableChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;

    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private List<ServerClient> clients = new List<ServerClient>();

    private float lastMovementUpdate;
    private float movementUpdataRate = 0.05f;


    private void Start() {
        NetworkTransport.Init();
        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null); // null means that server accepts every IPs to connect to it.
          //hostId = NetworkTransport.AddWebsocketHost(topo, port, null);

        isStarted = true;
    }

    private void Update() 
        {
        if (!isStarted)
            return;

        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;
        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
        switch (recData) {
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:    //2
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has connected");
                OnConnection(connectionId);
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:       //3
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                Debug.Log("Receiving from " + connectionId + ":" + msg);
                string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');

                switch (splitData[0]) {
                    case "NAMEIS":
                        OnNameIs(connectionId, splitData[1]);
                        break;
                    case "MYPOSITION":
                        OnMyPosition(connectionId, float.Parse(splitData[1]), float.Parse(splitData[2]), float.Parse(splitData[3]));
                        break;

                    default:
                        Debug.Log("Invalid message: " + msg);
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent: //4
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has disconnected");
                OnDisconnection(connectionId);
                break;
        }
             //Ask player for their position
             if (Time.time - lastMovementUpdate > movementUpdataRate) 
             {
              lastMovementUpdate = Time.time;
              string m = "ASKPOSITION|";
              foreach (ServerClient sc in clients) 
                m += sc.connectionId.ToString() + '%' + sc.position.x.ToString() + '%' + sc.position.y.ToString() +'%'+ sc.position.z.ToString() + '|';             
              m = m.Trim('|');

                Send(m, unreliableChannel, clients);
             }

    }
    private void OnConnection(int cnnId) {
        // Add him to a list
        ServerClient c = new ServerClient();
        c.connectionId = cnnId;
        c.playerName = "TEMP";
        clients.Add(c);

        // when the player joins the server, tell him his ID
        // Request his name and send the name of all the other players
        string msg = "ASKNAME|" + cnnId + "|";

        foreach (ServerClient sc in clients) {
            msg += sc.playerName + "%" + sc.connectionId + "|";
        }

        msg = msg.Trim('|');
        Send(msg, reliableChannel, cnnId);
    }

    private void Send(string message, int channelId, int cnnId) {
        List<ServerClient> c = new List<ServerClient>();
        c.Add(clients.Find(x => x.connectionId == cnnId));
        Send(message, channelId, c);
    }

    private void Send(string message, int channelId, List<ServerClient> c) {
        Debug.Log("Sending : " + message);
        byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
        foreach (ServerClient sc in c) {
            NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, sc.connectionId, channelId, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
        }

    }

    private void OnNameIs(int cnnId, string PlayerName) {
        // Link the name to the connenction Id
        clients.Find(x => x.connectionId == cnnId).playerName = PlayerName;
        // Tell everybody that a new player has connected
        Send("CNN|" + PlayerName + '|' + cnnId, reliableChannel, clients);
    }

    private void OnDisconnection(int cnnId) {
        //Remove this plyer from our client list
        clients.Remove(clients.Find(x => x.connectionId == cnnId));

        //Tell everyone that somebody else has disconnected
        Send("DC|" + cnnId, reliableChannel, clients);

    }

    private void OnMyPosition(int cnnId, float x, float y, float z) {
        clients.Find(c => c.connectionId == cnnId).position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

}
```

**PlayerMotor**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {

    private CharacterController controller;
    private float verticalVelocity;

    private void Start() {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        Vector3 inputs = Vector3.zero;

        inputs.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        inputs.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (controller.isGrounded) // if controller is on the ground
        {
            verticalVelocity = -1;
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))  // if it jumps
            {
                verticalVelocity = 10;
            }
        } else {
            verticalVelocity -= 14.0f * Time.deltaTime;
        }
            inputs.y = verticalVelocity;
            controller.Move(inputs * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```